# Is it a bad practice to return pointers to value types in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on a little command processor project and when implementing a parameter list, I want to be able to return nullptr from a method that otherwise would return an unsigned int.

I'm relatively new to the C/C++ way of thinking(mostly working with .NET, Java, Python and other managed languages)

I've come up with the following method:

```
unsigned int* GetUnsigned(char* paramName, unsigned int* defaultValue = nullptr) {
    std::string name(paramName);
    if(this->Exists(name)) {
        unsigned int tmp = (unsigned int)std::stoul(this->mParams[name], nullptr, 10);
        unsigned int *value = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
        memcpy(value, &tmp, sizeof(unsigned int));
        return value;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

It gets the job done, but it seems a little.. odd to me, still.

Is this considered a bad practice or is it the right way to do it?

Comment: Is this C or C++, please pick one. If C++ consider `std::optional<unsigned int>` to avoid a `new` or `malloc` which are prone to memory leaks if the caller is unaware they're responsible for that memory.

Comment: That is a bad practice, because... (A) you return a pointer when you don't need to, when you should preferably use `std::optional` or the old pattern of 'returning' by output reference with the `bool` return value indicating whether succesful. (B) that pointer is not typed to indicate who owns it, so it's not clear the caller should `free` it. But then, in C++, you should not use either `malloc`/`free` because those are from C, nor `new`/`delete` because the stdlib provides encapsulations that prevent you having to manage memory on such a low level - `std::optional`, `unique_ptr`, `vector` etc

Comment: the problem is that you are using raw owning pointers. Returning them from functions isnt the crux. Eg returning a non-owning raw pointer from a function is fine

Comment: btw a "C/C++ way of thinking" must be rather twisted. C and C++ are two different languages and their ways to manage memory are quite different

Comment: If you use std::optional, you won't even need your 2nd argument because you can do: `unsigned int val = this->GetUnsigned("42").value_or(0);`

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on an ARM microcontroller so.. C and C++ go hand in hand. std::optional seems to be the right tool. I didn't see it in my intellisense, because my standard was set to c++14 and not c++17. Thanks guys!

Comment: `C and C++ go hand in hand` that might be true, but they are still different languages with different concepts.

Answer (score 2):

As Cory and all of you have suggested: `std::optional` did the trick.
Also, as m88 suggested: I've replaced my 2nd argument with `.value_or(value)` which would have been the default return value in case the given parameter key was missing from the list.

Now the current implementation looks like this:

```
std::optional<unsigned int> GetUnsigned(const char* paramName) {
    if(this->Exists(paramName)) {
        return (unsigned int)std::stoul(this->mParams[paramName], nullptr, 10);
    }
    return {}; // Returning an empty optional
}
```

And the usage is the following:

```
void testFunc(CommandParameterList* params, ResponseBuilder* rbuilder) {
    /* ... */
    unsigned int value = params->GetUnsigned("Param2").value_or(100);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: you can turn this into an actual answer, but in its current state it isnt one. Note that questions and answers are supposed to be useful not only to you, but also to future readers.

Comment: you need to return also something in the else branch. `std::nullopt` via `return {};` returns an "empty" optional

Comment: I doubt you need the `name` variable. Just do `mParams[paramName]`.

Comment: `paramName` should probably be a pointer to const.