# C++ Parsing and Storing any kind of data

Tags: c++

I'm working on a text-based a simple command processor for a microcontroller project (C and C++). It implements an "explicit setter" so to speak. It means that I store pointers to target memory locations and set them to the incoming data.

First of cource, I parse the data based a predefined set of syntactical rules:

- "12345" -> string (char*)
- 12345 -> unsigned int
- 12.45 -> float
- -123456 -> int (signed)

This is the method I've come up with:

```
void* CommandInterpreter::ParseArgumentValue(std::string token, size_t* ptrSize = nullptr) {
    try { 
        void* value = NULL;
        if(std::count(token.begin(), token.end(), '.') == 1) {
            auto result = (float)std::atof(token.c_str());
            value = malloc(sizeof(float));
            ptrSize = sizeof(float);
            memcpy(value, &result, sizeof(float));
        } else if(token.front() == '"' && token.back() == '"') {
            const char* result = token.substr(1, token.size()-2).c_str();
            size_t size = (strlen(result) * sizeof(uint8_t)) + 1;
            value = malloc(size);
            ptrSize = size;
            memcpy(value, result, size);
        } else if(token.front() == '-') {
            auto result = (int)std::atoi(token.c_str());
            value = malloc(sizeof(int));
            ptrSize = sizeof(int);
            memcpy(value, &result, sizeof(int));
        } else {
            auto result = (unsigned int)std::stoul(token.c_str());
            value = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
            ptrSize = sizeof(unsigned int);
            memcpy(value, &result, sizeof(unsigned int));
        }
        return value;
    } catch(std::invalid_argument) {
        //return NULL;
    } catch(std::out_of_range) {
        //return NULL;
    }
}
```

I know it's not pretty, and it borders on bad-practice but it works.. however this will need to be freed after I process the value.

The actual setter-part looks like this:

```
auto setterdef = this->mDefinitions2[tokens[1]];
void* value = ParseArgumentValue(tokens[2]);
memcpy(setterdef.TargetPtr, value, setterdef.TargetSize);

  if(memcmp(setterdef.TargetPtr, value, setterdef.TargetSize) != 0)
        throw "COULD_NOT_SET";

free(value);
rbuilder.SetName("OK");
return rbuilder.Get();
```

The setter part works well, however I want to use the same function to parse an incoming parameter list and then store it in an `std::map<std::string, void*>` but this will keep the allocated memory even after the map is destroyed; as of right now I have a foreach in the destructor of my `CommandParameterList` class which frees the pointers in the map.. but it seems pretty odd to me.

My question would be.. how bad is this? And is there a better way to do this?

I know about `std::any` however, as far as I know I cannot just memcpy X amount of bytes from it, and I'd need to know the specific type to `std::any_cast` it.

Comment: In what world is `std::string` C?

Comment: `const char* result = token.substr(1, token.size()-2).c_str();` creates a temporary `string`, stores the `c_str()` of it in `result` and destroys the temporary `string`, which leaves `result` with a dangling pointer.

Comment: I said: C and C++ the microcontroller's HAL library is C so that's the C part..

Comment: You were told on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351920/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-return-pointers-to-value-types-in-c) to not use both C and C++ tags. And the code you have posted is clearly not C. You should not tag a question based on what it *contains*, but what it is *about*.

Comment: Yeah, my bad...

Comment: There are questions that qualifies for both tags, but those are very few ;)

Comment: @david20002062 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360824/6699433

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm more used to managed languages like C#, Java and Python at work and just now learning C++ (on a more professional level) and malloc and memcpy is sort of a so-low-level stuff to me that I consider them as C - as strange as it sounds

Comment: @david20002062 It doesn't sound strange. A c++ dev in 2021 shouldn't use C-API stuff like malloc, free, memcmp, memcpy, or even raw pointers outside of VERY SPECIFIC circumstances. You know `std::any` objects are copyable/movable without knowing the underlying type, right? Then why not return one and store it in `setterdef.TargetPtr`?

Comment: @m88 Well, because `setterdef.TargetPtr` is a void* which points to an actual variable like a uint8_t. Outside the objects related to the command interpreter.

Comment: @david20002062 What I was implying is that `setterdef.TargetPtr` should be a `std::any` to begin with. Do you really need it to be a `void*`?

Comment: @m88 My idea was this: take any kind of data.. anywhere in the code; store a pointer to it and when the set instruction comes in, set that memory directly. And hence the void*

Comment: @david20002062 You don't need that memset(). `std::any value = T()` will work whatever the T type is: float, bool, char[3], vector<vector<void(*)(bool)>>, whatever. You can even test what's inside the `std::any` with its `type()` method. At no point do you need `void*` to do what you intend to. Your `ParseArgumentValue()` will be shorter, safer (no memory leak or double free), more readable and easier to use (who has to call the free() right now?).

Comment: @m88 Right now, free has to be called after you are done with using the return void* from `ParseArgumentValue`, however the reason I cannot just store and `std::any` as `TargetPtr` is because the way I want it to work.. say for instance you have a variable, a global uint for instance.. or the member variable of an object (it sounds odd I know).. I want to be able to set them regardless of their defined type. Doing this with `std::any` would require them to be declared as type `std::any`

Comment: @david20002062 If you want a data buffer of size N, uint8_t[N] is also a valid type to store inside your `std::any`...  But whatever, you do you. Here's how it could look though: https://godbolt.org/z/EWx4os